# Read specific data from multiple files in different directories python

Tags: python, file, mean

If I have a number of files like this:

[[image: File Directory]]

Inside each folder is 3 more like this:

[[image: File Directory 2]]

Now inside each of these folders is a .txt file that looks like this:

[[image: .txt file]]

For each of the .txt files I need to get the value from the 6th column in the file which I have circled in red and I am only interested in the lines that contain cope1, cope2, cope3, cope4 and cope5 at the start (highlighted in blue). Everything else can be ignored.

I need to present the data separately for each folder

So would be:

[[image: result]]

I need to read in the relevant data from each of the files and store it in a sensible data structure.

All the data I need to present like this so that I have the mean value for FFA cope 1 - cope 5
and so on for each of the 3 folders within each of the 10 folders.

Presented roughly like this: 
[image: Required Output]

Apologies for the long winded question python newbie here! All help is greatly appreciated.

```js
import os
import csv
import statistics

def main():
    values = {}
    ffaResults = {}
    lingualResults = {}
    ppaResults = {}

    dir = os.path.join("fmriroi", "roi_data")
    subdirs = os.listdir(dir)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        subdirpath = os.path.join(dir, subdir)
        subsubdirs = os.listdir(subdirpath)
        for subsubdir in subsubdirs:

            if subsubdir == "ffa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in values:
                                    ffaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ffaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))  

            if subsubdir == "lingual_gyrus":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in lingualResults:
                                    lingualResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    lingualResults[name].append(float(row[6]))

            if subsubdir == "ppa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in ppaResults:
                                    ppaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ppaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))
    res = {}
    
    for k in ffaResults:
        res[k] = statistics.mean(values[k])
    print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output: required

[image: Output]

Comment: You should take a look at `os.listdir()` to run through your folders and also `pandas` to parse these .txt files.

Comment: I need to use a method alternate to pandas. I'll take a look at listdir

Comment: You could use the `csv` module then and specify space as a delimiter.

Comment: Would I need to convert all the files to csv?

Comment: No you don't, the `csv` module can read any text file. You would need to open your .txt file with `with open('my.txt', "r") as csvfile:` and then get the content with something like `content = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')`.

Comment: If you could post the content of the .txt  file so I could copy paste it I could write some piece of code as an answer

Comment: Thank you! I'm just a bit lost with this that would really help. The content is too long to include here so I have added the actual data with all files in here you can download. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b2279b8e4d99f86ab9b0b887c3e5128b20191122110614/22a09f

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b2279b8e4d99f86ab9b0b887c3e5128b20191122110614/22a09f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that I added to yours:

```py
import os
import csv
import pprint
import statistics

def main():
    values = {}
    ffaResults = {}
    lingualResults = {}
    ppaResults = {}

    dir = os.path.join("fmriroi", "roi_data")
    subdirs = os.listdir(dir)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        subdirpath = os.path.join(dir, subdir)
        subsubdirs = os.listdir(subdirpath)
        for subsubdir in subsubdirs:

            if subsubdir == "ffa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in values:
                                    ffaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ffaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))  

            if subsubdir == "lingual_gyrus":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in lingualResults:
                                    lingualResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    lingualResults[name].append(float(row[6]))

            if subsubdir == "ppa":
                dirpath = os.path.join(subdirpath, subsubdir)
                files = os.listdir(dirpath)
                for filename in files:
                    path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    with open(path, "r") as f:
                        content = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
                        for row in content:
                            if "cope" in row[1]:
                                name = row[1].split("/")[1]
                                if not name in ppaResults:
                                    ppaResults[name] = [float(row[6])]
                                else:
                                    ppaResults[name].append(float(row[6]))
    res = {"ffa": {}, "lingual": {}, "ppa": {}}
    for k in ffaResults:
        res["ffa"][k] = statistics.mean(ffaResults[k])
    for k in lingualResults:
        res["lingual"][k] = statistics.mean(lingualResults[k])
    for k in ppaResults:
        res["ppa"][k] = statistics.mean(ppaResults[k])

    pprint.pprint(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It gives the following output:

```
{'ffa': {'cope1': 0.4376,
         'cope2': 0.3582,
         'cope3': 0.6315,
         'cope4': 0.1722,
         'cope5': 0.3518},
 'lingual': {'cope1': -0.08865060000000001,
             'cope2': -0.150985,
             'cope3': -0.162005,
             'cope4': -0.130845,
             'cope5': -0.126411},
 'ppa': {'cope1': 0.74836,
         'cope2': 0.9444,
         'cope3': 0.300482,
         'cope4': 1.12435,
         'cope5': 0.8332200000000001}}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help this has really helped me! I have adapted your approach so that I am checking which folder I am in and seperating the results out seperately as I want to calculate the mean of FFA - Cope1 across all the files and so on for each one so I need to group all the FFA Cope1's together and so forth however im having trouble calculating the mean at the end and displaying this in a table here is what I have

Comment: This is what I have its too big to paste into here.

Comment: @wax_boi what do you mean by "table"?

Comment: @wax_boi you can add it to your question

Comment: I have added the code I have so far to the bottom of my question. As you can see I need to calculate the mean for all the Cope's in the different folders separately so I can then present them in a format like I have added to the bottom of my question.

Comment: so you can see I need the mean of all the Cope1's in the FFA folder all the Cope2's in the FFA folder and the same for the different folders rather than the mean of all them togther

Comment: That's brilliant thank you! I'm getting there! I think now I will be able to organise these how I need to and add the standard deviation etc.

Comment: You are welcome :) Feel free to mark the question as answered if you think it is (you can still add comments afterwards)

Comment: I have tried to for you! But I don't have enough rep :p first time asking questions in the community! As soon as I am able to publicly upvote I'll be sure to come back and do so! Thanks again!

Comment: I mean mark the question as answered, not upvote, even with 1 rep you should be able to do that as you are the one who asked the question :) (it should be next to the upvote button)

Comment: Found it! haha I thought they were the same thing!

Comment: Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation and add that to the results next to the mean for each one

Comment: @wax_boi you could use `statistics.stdev()` to compute the standard deviation

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Silveris suggestion in the comments. You can use my code for a single file:

```
import re

datas = []

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    i = 1
    data = {}
    for line in lines:
        cope = [item for item in line.split() if re.match(rf'cope{i}', item)]
        if cope != []:
            data[''.join(cope)] = line.split()[5]
            i += 1

datas.append(data)
```